How can my Mac application set the UTI of an output text file with a user-specified file extension?
I've written a Mac application (in Objective-C++) that writes several output files. They are all plain text files, but the user can name them with any desired file extension. My question is, how can my application set the UTI of those files to public.plain-text so that any other application that can read such files will be able to recognize and open them?
My info.plist includes a document type with a public.plain-text identifier, but I can't figure out how to associate that type with my output files. Since I can't predict my users' desired file extensions, I can't use those. I need to set the UTI within my code somehow. Otherwise, mdls just lists UTI information such as this:
kMDItemContentType                     = "dyn.ah62d4um4ge8087py"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "public.item",
    "dyn.ah62d4um4ge8087py",
    "public.data"
)

As you can see, I get a dynamic UTI (not surprisingly), but not the desired public.plain-text UTI.
I've scoured the Internet (including stackoverflow) for an answer, but no one else seems to have had the same problem, where the output file extension cannot be predicted by the application.
